# Async database creation with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, asynchronous, pthreads

I am building a system where every account has its own databases. Creating these databases when the user is actually creating the account results in a long wait before the page is refreshed. Logically, since php is still busy, so the page cannot finish.

Therefore my idea is to 'buffer' up a few, like 5 of these packages, all named $DBNAME$number, where number is 1 to 5. So I just rename the databases at account creation time, thereby minimizing the wait. I think this will work pretty well, but off course, I need to replenish my buffer.

That's where I figured I'd need a method to just replenish the database buffer in the background, which could even run while the accounts database is prepared, and the user is already logging in. 
The thing is, I haven't found a solution to this, while looking aroung a lot. I tried pthread, which runs exactly as if I would run the code inline. I even gave ajax a shot, hoping the .php file will run async, but it will not.

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to achieve this goal I have? 
PS: if xy problem, you may notify me ;)

Comment: "every account has its own databases" that is a real bad idea

Comment: I do understand your point, I felt like: 'will that be an advantage, or plain stupidity?'. I found http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/what-problems-will-i-get-creating-a-database-per-customer, and thought I should give it a shot.

Comment: i have done it, in a very particular circumstances so shouldn't condemn it outright. but 99.99999% if the time its a bad idea. as to an approach you can simply call a php script via exec to create the db in the background. but i create a 30 table db in less than a second - so i don't really see that it should be an issue

Comment: php is not async by definition. Even if you compile PHP with threads, you will not achieve a web success. You might need a little daemon that runs on background as a process. Fortunately PHP has a good api for working with processes.

Comment: Still stupid. Anyway, there's no `async`/`await` thingies as in .NET

Comment: Thanks @RoyalBg, I was thinking about that actually. Not to be an ask to ask person, but can you recommend any in particular?

Comment: Millions of ways to achieve your goal. You can have a little php script that recieves arguments in the standard input and being opened with `proc_open` and creates the database upon the given arguments. Think of it as a primitive console app

Answer (score -1):

try using a single database which contains all the accounts or try semaphores instead. like

wait function here
//your entire work here
 and exit function here
i hope this will work :)